# Can a "lightweight tag" point to a tree object or blob object?

Tags: git

I understand that in most cases, a lightweight tag points to a commit object.

According to https://www.theguild.nl/git-content-based-addressing-branches-and-tags/, I feel that, when a lightweight tag points to a tag object, the lightweight tag is in fact an annotated tag. (I feel that this statement is kinda weird, any correction is welcome)

My question is, Can a lightweight tag point to a tree object or blob object? If yes, how? and what's the meaning/real-world use for that.

Comment: A normal annotated tag named T has a lightweight tag named T pointing to a tag object that contains the line `tag T`. If you make a second lightweight tag T2 pointing to the same tag object, it's not clear to me whether to *call* that an annotated tag: words are tricky sometimes. :-)

Comment: In any case, yes, both a `refs/tags/<name>` entry, and an annotated tag object, can point to any kind of object. In fact, an annotated tag object can point to another annotated tag object. Git can keep following these objects until it arrives at a non-tag object: the gitrevisions syntax for this is a trailing `^{}` (with no object type in the braces).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a tag can reference blobs and trees.

```
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git-test/.git/
$ echo "Hello" > test.txt
$ git add test.txt 
$ git commit -m "INitial commit"
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob e965047ad7c57865823c7d992b1d046ea66edf78    test.txt
$ git tag test-tag -m "Test tag" e965047
$ git tag | cat
test-tag
$ git show test-tag | cat
tag test-tag
Tagger: Stephen Newell
Date:   Mon Apr 20 23:17:33 2020 -0600

Test tag
Hello
```

The use case is if you want to tag a specific blob or tree for whatever reason.  Why you'd want to do this depends on the person, but I've done it for hodgepodge repos where I want version control on files that are independent and I'm too lazy to make new repos for each one.

Comment: Passing the `-m` flag when creating the tag creates a tag object so is not a lightweight tag. However you are correct in that you can create a lightweight tag for a blob. `git tag special-file $(git hash-object -t blob -w special.txt)` would yield such a tag. If `git cat-file -t test-tag` says 'tag' it is a tag object. A lightweight tag gives the type of the tag target. (ie blob in this case)